# Dingo API - How to add version number in url?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dingo-api

I have just installed Dingo and it appear to work with the following URL:

http://website.dev/api/test

http://website.dev/api/hello

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
    $api->version('v1', function ($api) {

        $api->get('test', function () {
            return 'Test';
        });

        $api->get('hello', function () {
            return 'Hello';
        });

    });
```

I would like version v1 to be included in the URL, how do I get this to work?
When I try:

http://website.dev/api/v1/test

I get error:

```
{
"message": "404 Not Found",
"status_code": 404
}
```

In the `.env` file, I have: `API_PREFIX=api`

According to [Dingo Configuration](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Configuration):

> Avoid putting a version number as your prefix or subdomain as
>   versioning is handled via the Accept header.

Comment: Try this. https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Making-Requests-To-Your-API I hope this help you

Answer (score 7):

The version of dingoAPI don't work this way. Because they aren't versioning the API in the URI, you need to define an Accept header to request a specific version. The header is formatted like so:

```
Accept: application/vnd.YOUR_SUBTYPE.v1+json
```

For accessing the version you will need a HTTP Client like [postman](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVsom_la_OAhVFRo8KHZOUDQcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fpostman%2Ffhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNE_Yq59TT1ZExzJ68FTldg4ho_lGw&sig2=u-NFmsmpcVEsvswv4I7xuA)

Answer (score 4):

To work around the dingo version scheme, you could use route groups inside the version method and ignore the accept header. Something like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');


$api->version('v1', function ($api) { // Always keep this to v1, and ignore accept header.

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function ($api) { // Use this route group for v1

        $api->get('/', function () {
            return 'Look v1!';
        });

    });


    $api->group(['prefix' => 'v2'], function ($api) { // Use this route group for v2

        $api->get('/', function () {
            return 'Look v2!' ;
        });

    });

});
```