# Laravel route group is not taken properly

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I created 2 route groups in my api route file, and I can't access to routes of second group.

First group :

```
$api     = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$request = app('\Dingo\Api\Http\Request');

$api->dispatch($request);
/* API V1 ROUTES */

$prefix = 'test';

$api->group(['prefix' => $prefix,'version'=> 'v1'],function($api) {

    $api->post('/entity/validate/{code}', [
        'as'    => 'validate.code',
        'uses'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\XXX\Api\SmsController@validateCodeV1',
    ]);
});
```

This is working perfectly and I reach my function validateCodeV1 that does perfectly its job.
On another side I have right after it
Second group :

```
$prefix = 'testv2';
$api->group(['prefix' => $prefix,'version'=> 'v2'],function($api) {

    $api->post('/entity/validate/{code}', [
        'as'    => 'validate.code',
        'uses'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\XXX\Api\SmsController@validateCode',
    ]);
});
```

Here I have a 404 when I try to call my api with a prefix testv2/entity/validate/XXX

I don't know how I can specify properly my prefix to swap from my v1 route to my v2 route...
I use Laravel 5.5

EDIT : 
check of routes contains only one of my 2 routes, even after cache clear :

```
php artisan route:list | grep entity/validate
|        | POST                                   | /test/entity/validate/{code}                                                                       | validate.code                                | Closure                                                                                                    | api.controllers               |
```

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` show? Are both routes in there?

Comment: I have only the first one

Comment: even after a route cache refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by mixing the 2 solutions of this post : 
[Dingo API - How to add version number in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664222/dingo-api-how-to-add-version-number-in-url)
It is not exactly a duplicate so I let my post, but if someone think it is appropriated to remove my post just ask and I will do it

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and change the **$api->** to **Route::** and both work as they should and listed in php artisan route:list.

```
$prefix = 'test';
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix,'version'=> 'v1'],function($api) {
    Route::post('/entity/validate/{code}', [
        'as'    => 'validate.code',
        'uses'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\XXX\Api\SmsController@validateCodeV1',
    ]);
});

$prefix = 'testv2';
Route::group(['prefix' => $prefix,'version'=> 'v2'],function($api) {
    Route::post('/entity/validate/{code}', [
        'as'    => 'validate.code',
        'uses'  => 'App\Http\Controllers\XXX\Api\SmsController@validateCode',
    ]);
});
```

I think, you can check your $api or $request, maybe there is an error, function, or something else that only allow v1 version.

Comment: I tried this but sadly it is not working properly with Dingo... I am turning everything in all ways, but as I have a lot of ws i can't skip using Dingo at moment...